# ¿Cómo llamar desde el main a un método en el que he creado un array de objetos?

Tags: java

Como puedo comprobar desde el main que funciona este método?
Lo que quiero hacer es crear un método que inserte los datos de un numero de aspirantes y se me ocurrió crear un método y hacer un array del objeto, ahora al comprobarlo no se como llamar desde el main el método insertarAspirante

```
public class Aspirante {
    private int numero;
    private int telefono;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellidos;
    private String email;

    public Aspirante(int numero, int telefono, String nombre, String apellidos,String email){
        this.numero=numero;
        this.telefono=telefono;
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.apellidos=apellidos;
        this.email=email;    
    }

    public void insertarAspirante(String nombre,String apellidos,String email,int numero,int telefono){
        
        Aspirante arrayObjetos[]=new Aspirante[3];

        for(int i = 0; i<arrayObjetos.length;i++){
            nombre= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduzca el nombre:");
            apellidos= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduzca el apellido: ");
            email=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduzca su correo: ");
            numero= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduzca su numero: "));
            telefono= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduzca su telefono:"));
            
            arrayObjetos[i]= new Aspirante(numero,telefono,nombre,apellidos,email);   
        }

        for(int i=0; i<arrayObjetos.length;i++){
            System.out.println(arrayObjetos[i]);
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: El array de aspirante no puede ir en la clase aspirante, necesitas uan clase aspirantes y luego otra clase que lleve un array de aspirantes y entonces en esa clase va el metodo insertar. Por ejemplo clase contacto con nombre apelido.... clase agenda con un array de contactos que es donde ira añadir contacto eliminar contacto editar contacto y todo los metodos que quieras y luego ya tienes el main. No se si me explico

Comment: Si, entiendo lo que me quieres decir, el problema es que en el ejercicio me pide crear un método para insertar aspirantes y que inserte 3 desde la consola entonces no se que poner en el método si no puedo crear  un array de aspirante (me pide que haga el ejercicio en una clase llamada aspirante y comprobarla en el main )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero me crearía unos `setters/getters` en tu clase `Aspirante`. También un constructor sin parámetros, que será a quien llamaremos desde el `main()`

```
public int getNumero() {
    return numero;
}

public void setNumero(int numero) {
    this.numero = numero;
}

public int getTelefono() {
    return telefono;
}

public void setTelefono(int telefono) {
    this.telefono = telefono;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getApellidos() {
    return apellidos;
}

public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
    this.apellidos = apellidos;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public Aspirante() {
    
}
```

A tu método `insertarAspirante()` le quitaría los parámetros y le pondría una opción para elegir la cantidad de aspirantes a introducir

```
public void insertarAspirante() {
    
    int numAspirantes = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduzca la cantidad de aspirantes: "));
    Aspirante arrayObjetos[] = new Aspirante[numAspirantes];
```

Luego un `for` para mostrar los datos de los aspirantes utilizando los `getters`

```
 for (int i = 0; i < arrayObjetos.length; i++) {
     System.out.print("Nombre: " + arrayObjetos[i].getNombre() + " Apellido: " + arrayObjetos[i].getApellidos() + " Correo: " + arrayObjetos[i].getEmail() 
            + " Numero: " + arrayObjetos[i].getNumero() + " Telefono: " + arrayObjetos[i].getTelefono() + "\n");
 }
```

Y por ultimo, tendríamos en el `main()` la llamada a dicho método

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Aspirante aspirante = new Aspirante();
    aspirante.insertarAspirante();
}
```

**Código completo:**

**Clase Aspirante**

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Aspirante {
    private int numero;
    private int telefono;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellidos;
    private String email;

    public Aspirante() {
    
    }

    public Aspirante(int numero, int telefono, String nombre, String apellidos, String email) {
        this.numero = numero;
        this.telefono = telefono;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(int numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public int getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(int telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellidos() {
        return apellidos;
    }

    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void insertarAspirante() {
    
        int numAspirantes = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduzca la cantidad de aspirantes: "));
        Aspirante arrayObjetos[] = new Aspirante[numAspirantes];
    
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayObjetos.length; i++) {
            nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduzca el nombre:");
            apellidos = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduzca el apellido: ");
            email = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduzca su correo: ");
            numero = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduzca su numero: "));
            telefono = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduzca su telefono:"));

            arrayObjetos[i] = new Aspirante(numero, telefono, nombre, apellidos, email);
        }
    
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayObjetos.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Nombre: " + arrayObjetos[i].getNombre() + " Apellido: " + arrayObjetos[i].getApellidos() + " Correo: " + arrayObjetos[i].getEmail() 
                + " Numero: " + arrayObjetos[i].getNumero() + " Telefono: " + arrayObjetos[i].getTelefono() + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

**Main:**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Aspirante aspirante = new Aspirante();
        aspirante.insertarAspirante();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Nombre: DevMind Apellido: Guiber Correo: guiber@gmail.com Numero: 1234 Telefono: 4321
```

Comment: Ya me funciona Muchas gracias!!!